# How to calculate centroid of group of points in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

In Python, you could have e.g. a list of lists like `lst = [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4]]`.

To calculate the centroid in this, you could have the following code:

```
n = len(lst[0])
centroid = [0]*n

def centroid(*args):
    for i in range(n):
        _sum = sum([element[i] for element in lst])
        centroid[i] = _sum/len(lst)
    return centroid

get_centroid(lst)
```

How can I do the same thing in R for a group of points generally? I.e. how can the same function be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like they calculate the centroid coordinate-wise as the mean over the corresponding dimension, hence

```
lst <- list(c(0, 1, 2),c(2, 3, 4))

calcCentroid <- function(pointList) {
  rowMeans(do.call("cbind",pointList))
}

calcCentroid(lst)
```

should do the work.
I assume you have the points in a `list` and every point has the same `length`.
Then, you can combine them all together to a numeric matrix. Its columns contain the points. Then you can perform a rowwise mean, which in `R`can be done via `rowMeans`, which is a highly optimized function just for this job.